# How to find a subset in a nested list which has the highest sum of their elements in python?

Tags: python, subset, nested-lists

I am looking for a way to find a subset in a nested list which has the highest sum of their innerelements.

Here is my nested list is:

```
 ntdList=[
[1, 2, 3, 1],
[3, 3, 1, 10],
[1, 3, 2, 1],
[3, 4, 2, 1],
]
```

Suppose I want to subset it. The subset must be arranged in a specific shape: two rows and three columns. Let's call it sublist 2 X 3, which means a list of lists with two inner lists and 3 elements per list.
Here is an example of a subset.

```
subSet=[[1,2,3],[3,3,1]]
```

But now there is an additional step. I am looking for a best place to subset. For best I mean the highest sum of inner elements.

So, the conditions are:
(i) Keep the subset shape, as explained above, and
(ii) produces the highest sum of inner values.

According these two rules, the best positing to put my subset is the following position: from ntdList[0][1:4] to ntdList[1][1:4]. The result is 20. Similarly, from ntdList[1][1:4] to ntdList[2][1:4]. The result is also 20.

I tryed the code below but there is a problem ("list index out of the range") and I could not handle this. The results  are being stored but the problem of "list index out of the range" remains.

Besides that I am not sure if I made it correctly.

Here is my code:

```
sumList=[]
for row in range(2): # number of rows (inner list)
    for col in range(3): # number of columns (elements of inner list)
        sumList.append(
            
            sum(
                [
                    sum(ntdList[row][col:col+3])
            ,
            sum(ntdList[row+1][col:col+3])
                ]
            )
        )

print(sumlist) # [13, 20, 15, 11, 13, 20, 14, 11, 15, 13, 6, 2]
max(sumList) # 20
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Let me see if I understood correctly. You have a flat list. You want to convert this to a list of lists. Does each list have n number of items. And do these items go from 1 to n, 2 to n+1, 3 to n+2,.... until you reach the length of list? Then you want to find the max of the sublist?

Comment: I tried to describe the whole scenario, but you are right, it is confusing. I want to extract a subset from a nested list. This subset must obey a previous specificied size and shape ( 3rd and 4th numbers in the flat list).I have to find a best location to put the subset in the original nested list. The best place is where the sum of elements are the highest possible. The last code I wrote above is my atempt.

Comment: Are you saying that the subset is undefined and we need to figure out what subset will give the max result? In other words, the subset can be a list of 2 elements or 3 elements or 4 elements. And that each subset length has to be same? If so, there are a lot of possibilities starting from dividing the list into two, then into three, then into four, until we reach to a subset of 1 element each. Do you consider 1 element as a subset? Are you looking fort the max value of all the subsets?

Comment: Let's suppose the subset is a 2 X1 matrix. So, each subset must have two rows and one column. Now,  we have to find out which subset have the highest sum of inner elements. The output  I am looking for is the maximum sum of values found.

Comment: Let's make it easy for the community. In your question section, put the following things: Your input list, what you think should be the subset list, and the expected output from that subset list. That will make it easy for everyone to know what you are thinking / trying to do. And then provide an answer. Otherwise we are going to keep guessing what you want.

Comment: I am going to edit it now for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the list withe the highest sum or the index

```
neasted_list = [[1,2,3],[2,3,3],[3,2,4], [1,2,3]]
max_ = list(map(sum,neasted_list))
# get the list
print(neasted_list[max_.index(max(max_))])
# get the index
print(max_.index(max(max_)))
```